# how to call method in one component and it will call another method in another component?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am new to angular, so component extend is confusing for me. I have two components like header and content. so I have a method like filterChange() in the header component, so when I call this method it should call another method in another component. I tried @input and @output but in there I can't able to call the methods.

header component html:

```
<mat-radio-group[(ngModel)]="visibility" (ngModelChange)="filterChange()">
  <mat-radio-button [value]=null>true</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let visibility of jobVisibilities"
                        [value]="visibility">false</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

header component ts:

```
filterChange(){
 }
```

this is my code. I tried services also but there I don't know how to do this.
how to do this? please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Lets say u have 2 components ***HeaderComponent.ts*** and ***ContentComponent.ts***    
    U want to call the test() function from header component, which is in Content component
    
    * Import the ***content component*** 
    
    import {classname} from ./../content.component.ts;
    
    * Give the dependency injection
    
    constructor(){ public content : classname }
    
    filterChange(){
    
    /*you can call any content component function here*/
    
    let sample = this.content.test()
    console.log(sample)
    }
```

Comment: wow! thanks @lliyas...without using service I got this answer.